# How to Print Something Your Screen, Like The Right Bottom Corner of Your Screen

Tags: python

I've been trying to figure out how to print something to your screen, but every time I search it up, it comes up with the print() function, which is not what I'm looking for.

Current, I have this code:

```
print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')
try:
    while True:
        x, y = pyautogui.position()
        positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
        f = open('Bruh Moment.txt', 'a')
        f.write(positionStr)
        f.write('\n')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    f.close()
    print('OK Boomer')
```

This code is printing to a notepad file, but I want it to print in the corner of my screen (not the terminal/console)

How would I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simple way to display text on screen in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45427411/simple-way-to-display-text-on-screen-in-python)

Comment: not really, i was just looking to print text on my screen in a certain area